# FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, gremlin, async.js, amazon-neptune

I have the following snippet, in which I am trying to execute 10000 execute statement to understand that how many writes that Gremlin can withstand.

```
var gremlin = require('gremlin');
var async = require('async');
var client = gremlin.createClient(8182, "development.cluster-coeuolcg4r.us-east-1-beta.rds.amazonaws.com", {
    accept: "application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json"
});

console.time('load');
async.times(10000,  function (t, tCB) {
    client.execute('g.addV("loadtest#1-50000#2").property("idx", '+new Date().getTime()+')', function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        tCB(null, 1);
    });
}, function () {
    console.timeEnd('load')
});
```

It is a simple snippet while running this I am getting an error and program execution gets stop.

[image]

It is working as expected if I ran this snippet for 5000.

Side note: --max-old-space-size didn't worked.

Comment: Do you have any updates or followups with regards to this question?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look related to Neptune. Looks more like a client side setting that you need to tweak. I don't see any mention of your environment details (OS, or Node version), but I would definitely start with looking at your ulimits and prlimits of the system.